# Mergin Maps measure function available

Tags: line, area, measurements, mergin-maps

Project works find. I use [Mergin Maps](https://merginmaps.com/) on Windows 11.

But I need an essential function: Measure area and lines

Is there no function for that?

Comment: Please provide some details. What is your setup, what are you trying to achieve, etc.

Answer (score 2):

It's not supported to calculate directly in the app, but if you use the field calculator in QGIS to create area and length fields they should populate the values when you sync in Mergin Maps.

Comment: ok, good idea, but its to laborious for us. we need the result directly.

Comment: @Volk_a you may create request in https://wishlist.merginmaps.com

Answer (score 0):

I cannot find any reference to "Area" or "Length" being able to be calculated from within the app.

It may be that the App has been set up as purely a data capture tool. Any further geoprocessing may need to happen post-sync / post-capture using QGIS or another GIS System.

Comment: https://github.com/MerginMaps/input/issues/1400